# onchange attribute won't call function

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have an HTML document ([here](http://www.wikiupload.com/download_page.php?id=196262)), which creates an iframe-based media player for a collection of songs within albums (I just used letters to define these albums and songs in the mymusic array, for simplicity).

Focusing on the top 3 iframes, the way I have set out the user interaction is to generate the HTML for forms of available albums and songs using Javascript, and write them to the iframes in the body. If you run it and make a selection in the **Albums** menu, you will see that the options in the **Songs** menu correspond with the `mymusic` array, so this works.

However, when I choose a song, the function `nowplaying(trackindex,albumindex)` should be called using an `onchange` event in the **Songs** form, the same way as in the form generated using `showinitial()` ... but the function does not get called.

I have ruled out the coding of `nowplaying` itself as a cause, because even when I change `nowplaying` to `alert("hello")`, it does not get called. So this leads me to think the problem is with the `onchange` attribute in "anything", but I can't see the problem. The way I coded it is no different to before, and that worked fine, so why won't this work?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug is your friend....

> i is not defined
>
> function
> onchange(event) {
> parent.nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex,
> i); }(change )

onchange is getting called, but `i` is not defined when calling `nowplaying`.

This is the result of this line:

```
p+="<html><head></head><body><form><select onchange='parent.nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex,i);' size='";
```

which is using "i" in the string, when it should append it as a variable:

```
p+="<html><head></head><body><form><select onchange='parent.nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex," + i + ");' size='";
```

To clarify, `i` is defined when `anything(i)` is called, but you aren't writing `i` into the code, just the letter "i".  When `nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex,i)` is called, `i` is no longer defined, because you aren't inside of the `anything()` function anymore.  You need to expand `i` when you append the html to `p`, so that the value is there and not the variable `i`.

Comment: But "i" is defined...it's the value that I'm passing into the function "anything" ?

Comment: The problem is that you are using "i" as a string and not a variable.  You are doing p+="blah blah i blah", instead of p+="blah blah "+i+" blah".  See my edits.

Comment: Thanks. I've now tried it with that edit, and I get the error console saying "mymusic[albumindex].tracks[trackindex].tracktitle is undefined"...but I can't see how it's undefined as the mymusic and tracks arrays are defined, and albumindex and trackindex should both take the value of numbers being passed into the function

Comment: You need to add parent to that. You are calling it from the context of the frame:
parent.mymusic[albumindex].tracks[trackindex].tracktitle

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I've just done that for both of the instances where i mentioned "mymusic...." within function nowplaying, and it still doesn't write to the iframe...i put an alert(q) in after I've finished building q, and that doesn't happen either. So I really don't know what's up now!

Comment: http://www.wikiupload.com/download_page.php?id=196269

I guess the crux of my frustration is, why isn't it working the second time, if it works the first time, and I'm doing it exactly the same?!

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: this.SelectedIndex should be this.selectedIndex

Comment: Oh dear! I can't believe it was something as trivial as that, most likely a typing error on my part. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate you taking the time to go through it yourself :-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
function anything(i){
    p+="...<select onchange='parent.nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex,i);'...";
```

Your onchange event handler is set from a string. When run, it will not have access to `i`, which is a local variable from the `anything` function that has long since gone away.

The simple fix would be:

```
    p+="...<select onchange='parent.nowplaying(this.SelectedIndex,'+i+');'...";
```

which turns the current value of `i` at string-making time into an integer literal inside the string.

However, it's not generally a good idea to be creating code from strings. It's normally better to write the event handler as a normal function object:

```
// You will need the below workaround to get the iframe document in IE too
//
var iframe= document.getElementById('songs');
var idoc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;

idoc.open();
idoc.write(s);
idoc.close();

idoc.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange= function() {
    // This is a closure. The 'i' variable from the parent 'anything' function is
    // still visible in here
    //
    parent.nowplaying(this.selectedIndex, i);
};
```

However you would generally want to avoid setting handlers from one frame on a different one. I'm not really sure what the iframes are gaining you here other than headaches. Why not just simply use positioned divs with overflow? You can still rewrite their content through `innerHTML` if you need to... though I would prefer to populate them using DOM methods, to avoid all the HTML-injection problems your current script has.